# Multiple imports on one line frown upon?

Tags: python

I'm aware of this convention to keep each import on its own line but from **technical standpoint** is there any difference between:

```
import sys, os
```

or

```
import sys
import os
```

Personally, I have no problem to keep both on one line unless there's really good reason not to do so.

If this topic gets closed for being opinionated I'll take it as there's no valid reason for giving imports its own line.

Does Python treats the imports differently in any circumstances ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Module Import: Single-line vs Multi-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011367/python-module-import-single-line-vs-multi-line)

Comment: Maybe this answers your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011367/python-module-import-single-line-vs-multi-line

Comment: It does. Thank you. Technically speaking no difference at all.